# Symfony / Sylius site on Vagrant / Puphpet is slow. Same site not on a Virtualbox is not slow

Tags: symfony, vagrant, sylius, puphpet

We have one particular site that is Symfony and uses the e-commerce bundle Sylius.

Our developers are trying to use Vagrant so we can have similar dev environments. We use Puphpet to generate the Vagrant instance and share the config file.

If we are working on the site/repo natively or on a staging server, all runs fine. Pages load in around 2-3 seconds.

When we are using Vagrant / Virtualbox, it's 30-35 seconds per page load.

So far we've tried

- Allocating up to 6GB to the box
- Giving up to 4 processors to the box
- Turning on NFS for file sync
- Turning off all other programs on computers running Vagrant / Virtualbox (chat, other browsers, etc)

None of those things made an impact on page load time.

I can provide 2 things. One is the load trace from Symfony: https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/708707/mvw707mckzm2wq4rlkzc

Since there is so much code to the puphpet config, I put it in a pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/7ciVA5FL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[vagrant-winnfsd](https://github.com/winnfsd/vagrant-winnfsd) works fine for me for getting NFS to work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

What is OS on a host machine?

My guess would be that file system is slow. Try to run an app outside of shared folder on the guest machine. If it will be fast, then you'll spot a problem at least.

NFS on *nix or mac should be fast enough, are you sure you've succeed to turn it on?

I had this pain once, and finally started to use unison instead of native vagrant's file sharing system (https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/)

Comment: Host machines are Windows 10 32bit, 8GB ram 15 fourth gen. I added nfs to the file sync and did a vagrant reload --provision. Not sure how to check if it took or not. If I have to, I can peek into unison too.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that NFS wasn't working. I tried to do the same on Windows machine, and it just doesn't work out of the box - vagrant just keeps using its virtual box sharing mechanism.

Comment: Noted. I will dig into NFS and see if I can get that working then. Thank you for your help! I will keep you posted

Comment: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/nfs.html It says right there, NFS does not work on Windows.

Comment: I found a solution that makes it work on Windows. https://github.com/winnfsd/vagrant-winnfsd I got it down to 4-5 seconds per page. Still slow, but at least acceptable

Comment: This is offtop, but I would recomment not to use Vagrant at all. Docker serves much better, and the performance is only one of the wins

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried:

- http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/08/19/speedup_symfony2_on_vagrant_boxes.html
- or http://jeremybarthe.com/2015/02/02/speed-up-vagrant-environment-symfony2/

I think the first one is already included in Sylius, but not sure.

Also, dynamic image resize/crop may be reading/writing in the host file system and maybe there's a way to also change that (using symlinks or similar)?

Comment: github.com/winnfsd/vagrant-winnfsd works fine for me for getting NFS to work on Windows